# Are code or design reviews acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope

Do we want code or design reviews on this site?

Code reviews expect considerable effort on the part of readers, more than a typical question. Furthermore, they are very open-ended — “I can't see anything wrong with this code” is a valid, but not that interesting answer (and what about “I can't see anything wrong either”, which is a *different* answer for every “I”?). Design reviews require less reading effort, but suffer from the same problem with answers.

This has been discussed about [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) before. The discussions I could find are:

- [Is Stack Overflow an appropriate place for simple code reviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28540/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-place-for-simple-code-reviews)
- [Should SO allow "give me some feedback" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/should-so-allow-give-me-some-feedback-questions)
- [Where can I post code for others to review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90362/where-can-i-post-code-for-others-to-review)

There is now a [Code Review Stack Exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but this should not influence our stance of what's acceptable on *this* site too much.

This meta question was triggered by [What else could I lock down for buildbot runs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18683/what-else-could-i-lock-down-for-buildbot-runs).

Comment: "I can't see anything wrong with this code" should always be a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I think they're too localized -- they can't possibly help anyone except the original asker. They're allowed on Code Review because that's the entire purpose of the site, but I wouldn't expect them to be allowed on any other SE site

Comment: I disagree that *they can't possibly help anyone except the original asker*, but I agree with the fact they should be offtopic here, and instead asked on Code Review.

Comment: +1. I agree with @Tshepang that they are often of iterest to more than the OP or the Code Review site wouldn't have even survived this long. Everybody can benifit from a good review / comment set. However I don't think the question in question should be on-topic as-written and that "too localized" is an acceptable close reason.